# Light Reflection Disc On Object Three-js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am creating an earth scene with Three-js and have things working pretty well except for the giant obnoxious reflection disc that is present on the surface of the earth object.  Any ideas on removing the reflection or at least lessening it to a great degree?

[image: Image of Reflection Anomaly-]

Lighting-

```
//renderer
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { canvas : spaceCanvas} );
    renderer.setSize( 672, 472 );
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    renderer.shadowMap.renderReverseSided = false;
//mainScene
    mainScene = new THREE.Scene();
    mainCamera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth /window.innerHeight, 0.01, 2000 );
    mainCamera.position.z = 2.25;
//Lighting
    var ambLight    = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x222222 );
    var light   = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 1 );
    light.position.set(5,3,5);
    light.castShadow = true;
    light.shadow.camera.near = 0.01;
    light.shadow.camera.far = 15;
    light.shadow.camera.fov = 45;
    light.shadow.camera.left = -1;
    light.shadow.camera.right =  1;
    light.shadow.camera.top =  1;
    light.shadow.camera.bottom = -1;
    /*light.shadowCameraVisible = true;*/
    light.shadow.bias = 0.001;
    light.shadow.mapSize.width = 672;
    light.shadow.mapSize.height = 472;
    mainScene.add(light, ambLight);
```

Earth Object-

```
function CreateEarth(){
earth = new THREE.Object3D();
THREE.crossOrigin = "";
    var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    var colorMap = loader.load("img/bodies/earth/colorMap.jpg");
    var bumpMap = loader.load("img/bodies/earth/bump.jpg");
    var specMap = loader.load("img/bodies/earth/specular.jpg");
    var earthGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 0.5, 32, 32 );
    var earthMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        map : colorMap,
        bumpMap : bumpMap,
        bumpScale : 0.05,
        specularMap : specMap,
        specular : new  THREE.Color("grey"),
        shininess: 25
    });
    earthMesh = new THREE.Mesh(earthGeometry, earthMaterial );
    earth.add(earthMesh);

function CreateEarthAtmosphere(){
    var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    var cloudTexColorMap = loader.load("img/bodies/earth/cloudTexture.png");

    var atmosphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.51, 32, 32);
    var atmosphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
            map : cloudTexColorMap,
            /*alphaMap : cloudTexTransMap,*/
            side : THREE.DoubleSide,
            opacity : 0.5,
            transparent : true,
            depthWrite : false
    });
    atmosphereMesh = new THREE.Mesh(atmosphereGeometry, atmosphereMaterial);
    earthMesh.add(atmosphereMesh)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `shininess: 25` value may be affecting it's shininess when creating the earth material object.

```
var earthMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        map : colorMap,
        bumpMap : bumpMap,
        bumpScale : 0.05,
        specularMap : specMap,
        specular : new  THREE.Color("grey"),
        shininess: 25 // lower this?

});
```

Comment: I honestly overlooked that entirely.  I could have sworn  changed that before and it did not work.  However  adjusted it and it has the desired effect.